# Recovering a rank-one matrix from its eigendecomposition after randomized rounding

Tags: linear-algebra, pr.probability

Let $A = xy^T$ be a rank-$1$ matrix, and suppose every entry of $A$ is in $[0,1]$. We can create a binary matrix $A_{\rm rounded}$ by setting 
$$ [A_{\rm rounded}]_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{ with probability } A_{ij} \\ 0 & \mbox{ with probability } 1-A_{ij} \end{cases} $$

Is it possible to recover $x$ by looking at the principal eigenvector of $A_{\rm rounded}$? In other words, suppose $v$ is the principal eigenvector of $A$; is it true that, after rescaling $v$ and $x$ to have unit norm, the two vectors are nearly the same? In particular, can one show that $P( || \frac{x}{||x||_2} - \frac{v}{||v||_{2}} ||_{\infty} \geq \epsilon)$ goes to zero for any $\epsilon > 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

I wrote a quick MATLAB simulation that suggests the answer is yes. Here is my code:

> n=20000; %matrix size
>
> %generate matrix;
>
> x = rand(n,1);
>
> y = rand(n,1);
>
> A = x*y';
>
> %generate rounded matrix
>
> B = zeros(n,n);
>
> for i=1:n
>
> ```
> for j =1:n
>
>     if rand>A(i,j)
>
>         B(i,j)=0;
>
>     else
>
>         B(i,j) =1;
>
>     end
>
> end
> ```
>
> end
>
> %eigendecomposition of B
>
> [v,d]=eig(B);
>
> %figure out the index of the principal eigenvector;
>
> m = max(abs(d));
>
> mm = max(m);
>
> i = find(m==mm);
>
> %compare principal eigenvector to true answer
>
> y = v(:,i)/norm(v(:,i)) - x/norm(x);
>
> norm(y,inf)

Running this code with matrix size of 20,000 took me a few hours and returned $|| v/||v||_2 - x/||x||_2 ||_{\infty} \approx 0.02$, suggesting that the answer is positive. Since the answer is likely yes, is this something that is present in the literature? And is there a simple argument to see that recovery is possible, in this or a related model?

(I previously [asked this question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309441/recovering-a-rank-one-matrix-from-its-eigendecomposition-after-randomized-roundi) without receiving an answer.)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. The code doesn't recover $y$: I use the variable $y$ in the code for $v./x$. Eventually, I'd be curious to recover $A$, but my first question was whether this algorithm recovers $x$; if so, you could use the same approach to recover $y$ and recover $A$ at least up to scaling. My intuition is that this is similar to the model where you are given $A=xy^T + W$ where $W$ is noise, and in that case, recovery is possible if the $W$ is small enough (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870811000570 ). Here noise is not small but you compensate with many samples.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that the behavior for _random_ x and y (as your code tests) has any bearing on what should hold for _all_ x and y? That seems far-fetched to me.

Comment: The condition you are currently proposing for $x$ and $v$ to be "the same" is very weak.  E.g., in the example in your post, surely w.h.p. you will have $\|x\|_2 \approx \sqrt {n/2}$, so $\max_i x_i/\|x\|_2 \le \sqrt{2/n} \approx 0.01$.  So $\big\|v/\|v\|_2 - x/\|x\|_2\big\|_\infty \approx 0.02$ is not surprising, and says little about $v$ and $x$ being similar. E.g., it will hold for any $v$ such that $|v\|_2 \approx \sqrt{2/n}$ and $v_i \le 1$.  You probably need to use a norm other than the $\infty$ norm, or you need $\epsilon$ to decrease with $n$.  See also Remark 1 in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, as the question is currently formulated, the answer is no.

Here is a proposed counterexample. Fix arbitrarily large $n$.  Take $xy^T$ to be the matrix having each coordinate equal to $\delta/n$, for a sufficiently small constant $\delta>0$ (so $x$ is uniform). $A$ is then a random matrix where each entry is $1$ with probability $\delta/n$ and otherwise zero.

Here is a proof that this is indeed a counterexample to the conjecture in the post.

**Lemma 1.** *With probability $\Omega(\delta)$, $A$ has a dominant eigenvector $v'$ such that* $$\Big\|\frac{x}{\|x\|_2} - \frac{v'}{\|v'\|_2}\Big\|_\infty = \Big|\frac{1}{\sqrt n} - 1\Big| \approx 1.$$

*Proof.* Consider the directed graph $G=(V,E)$ with adjacency matrix $A$, that is $V=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $E=\{(i,j) : A_{ij} = 1\}$.  So $G$ is a random digraph where each possible edge (including self-loops) is independently present with probability $\delta/n$.

Let $X$ be the event that $G$ has a directed cycle of length 2 or more.  By the naive union bound, the probability that there is such a cycle is less than $\sum_{\ell\ge 2} n^\ell (\delta/n)^\ell = \sum_{\ell\ge 2} \delta^\ell = \delta^2/(1-\delta)$.

Let $Y$ be the event that $G$ has at least one vertex $i$ with a self-loop but no other outgoing edges.  (That is, $A_{ii}=1$ and every other entry in row $i$ is zero.)  By calculation, event $Y$ happens with probability about $1-e^{-\delta/e^\delta} = \Omega(\delta)$.

So the probability that $Y$ happens and $X$ does not is $\Omega(\delta) - O(\delta^2) = \Omega(\delta)$.
Assume that $Y$ happens and $X$ does not.  Because $Y$ happens, there is a row $i$ of $A$ where $A_{ii} =1$ but all other entries are zero.  So $A$ has an eigenvector $v'$ where $v'_{i} = 1$ is the only non-zero entry.  But $x_i/\|x\|_2 = 1/\sqrt n$, so, for this eigenvector,
$$\Big\|\frac{x}{\|x\|_2} - \frac{v'}{\|v'\|_2}\Big\|_\infty = \Big|\frac{1}{\sqrt n} - 1\Big| \approx 1.$$

To finish, we show that $v'$ is a dominant eigenvector, that is, that the largest eigenvalue of $A$ is 1.  Consider any eigenvector $v$.  Let $\lambda$ be the eigenvalue of $v$, so $Av = \lambda v$.  Let $C=\{i : v_i > 0\}$ be the support of $v$.  Consider the subgraph $G_C$ induced by $C$ (as a set of vertices in $G$).  Since $X$ does not happen, $G_C$ has no cycle of length 2 or more, so each strongly connected component of $G_C$ is a single vertex.  Hence, $G_C$ contains a single vertex $i$ having no incoming edges in $G_C$, except possibly a self-loop.  Now, because $v$ is an eigenvector with support $C$, this implies $A_{ii} v_i = \lambda v_i$.  Since $v_i>0$ this implies $\lambda =A_{ii} \in\{0, 1\}$. $~~\Box$

I think that the above argument suggests that $G$ can have multiple dominant eigenvectors (each with eigenvalue 1), and that some of those eigenvectors could have larger support --- size $\Omega(\log n)$, maybe? And such an eigenvector $v$ could have $\max_i v_i/\|v\|_2 = O(1/\log n)$, and so could meet the proposed condition for being "the same" as $x$.  But see Remark 1 below.

---

**Remark 1.** The condition currently suggested in the post for $x$ and $v$ to be "the same", namely,
$$\Big\|\frac{x}{\|x\|_2} - \frac{v}{\|v\|_2}\Big\|_\infty \le \epsilon,$$
seems to be too weak. It can only be violated if $x$ or $v$ has at least one very large coordinate.

For example, suppose the first $n/2$ coordinates of $x$ are 1 and the rest are zero, while the first $n/2$ coordinates of $v$ are zero, and the rest are 1.  Then $x$ and $v$ are *orthogonal*, so arguably not at all "the same".  But $x_i/\|x\|_2 \le \sqrt{2/n}$ and $v_i/\|v\|_2 \le \sqrt{2/n}$, so, assuming $n \ge 2/\epsilon^2$, the suggested condition is satisfied.

Of course, if the condition were strengthened, the counterexample above should still hold...

---

**Remark 2.** Tangentially, the behavior of eigenvectors of sparse random graphs (where the edge probability is around $1/n$ or so), seems to be fairly complicated.  Among the references I found, the most relevant to the argument was [1].  It considers the case when $\delta$ is just below 1, and shows that each strongly connected component of $G$ is either a single vertex or a cycle of constant size (possibly with self-loops).

The case when the edge probability is slightly larger, above $\log(n)/n$, say, seems to be more well studied, and in that case I think (although I'm not sure) that the eigenvectors of $G$ are more uniform.  Search Google Scholar for "eigenvectors of sparse random graphs".

[1]  Luczak, T. and Seierstad, T. G.. The critical behavior of random digraphs. Random Structures and Algorithms 35, 271-293 (2009).
http://folk.uio.no/taralgs/artikler/digraph.pdf